# Silverlight Faults

Tags: wcf, silverlight, faults

I;m trying to get WCF Silverlight faults working as per this :
[MSDN aricle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470096(VS.96).aspx)

After adding the SL fault to my Web.config file I get the following warning:

> The element 'behavior' has invalid child element 'silverlightFaults'. List of possible elements expected: 'serviceAuthorization, serviceCredentials, serviceMetadata, serviceSecurityAudit, serviceThrottling, dataContractSerializer, serviceDebug, serviceTimeouts, persistenceProvider, workflowRuntime'.

Ignoring the warning doesn't work and my Silverlight application cannot add the WCF service.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post the relevant part of your web.config, without it all anybody can do is guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

When you add the behavior extension, the type specification must be on a single line. No CRLF allowed in that section.

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="silverlightFaults" type="SilverlightFaultBehavior, Utilities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another potential cause:  Make sure your fully qualified name is EXACTLY correct - including whitespace (i.e. you need the spaces after the commas etc).

If you're feeling paranoid, you might want to set a debug point somewhere in your app and pop something like this into the watch window:

`typeof(SilverlightFaultBehavior).AssemblyQualifiedName`

and then copy/paste the value.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/98385/273886.aspx.
Basically, you did not specify the full assembly info in the behavior extension section or your version number is out of synch with the assembly.